# Twilio - Wait for all participants before entering a room and starting recording (small group rooms)

Tags: node.js, angular, twilio, twilio-video

I'm using small groups (max of 4 participants) and I have enabled recordings on it.
My use case it that the participants enters a lobby with video preview only (not recorded yet) and then he actually enters in the room (recording starts) and he can see all other participants there. And this is working as expected.

The problem is that when one participants enters the room, he can wait for other participants for several minutes before all of them arrive and we get a one person recording which we don't need at the moment, also we are "loosing money" on waiting for others.

The solution would be to know when everyone is ready to enter the room and then do it and start the recording. I had a hard time doing this with the data I get back from twilio as in order to get any data on the users the participants have to be connected in the room, which will start the recording. Another approach I was thinking of was to create a sample room (without recordings), kind of waiting room, and once everyone is ready just start the recording. I hope that the price for the sample room will be smaller so we can get the charges down. However pause/restart recording is stated as an unsupported feature in twilio docs and as I saw the price for a small group room is same with or without recordings enabled which doesn't help. I need something like GoRooms but for 4 participants.

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: You have have to handle that type of logic on your own server side application and your client UI. I would use websockets on the client side and when the presenter or leader is ready, he clicks on and everyone can join the room.

Answer (score 1):

This is outside the scope of Programmable Video, maybe you can look into using Twilio Sync, to coordinate the room participants to ensure they are assembled before creating and joining them to a room.

[Sync](https://www.twilio.com/sync)

[Sync Blogs](https://www.twilio.com/blog/search?q=sync)

[Sync Code Exchange](https://www.twilio.com/code-exchange?q=&f=sync)

Comment: It's not what I wanted to hear, but thanks any way. Took a look at sync, and although it looks cool we took our app in another direction. We are handling everything on our side, before opening the room from twilio.